# How to set marker color separately in matplotlib

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matplotlib, charts, beautifulsoup

Having a problem with 2D lines. What i want to do is to plot a chart that would have such info:

```
TEST1   1 0 0  
TEST2   1 1 1
TEST3   0 0 1
```

Where when there is 1 in results so there should be a green bubble and when zero - red one. 
I have tried(given example of matplotlib) :
http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_fillstyle_reference.html

However, i could not understand how to plot each bubble depending on its value.
Tried to make 3 different arrays and do offset on X axis, but somehow it did not work... Any thoughts how can i do this?
Adding some code that i tried to write:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D


points = np.ones(2)  # Draw 3 points for each line
print points
text_style = dict(horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center',
                  fontsize=16, fontdict={'family': 'monospace'})
marker_style_red = dict(color='red', linestyle=':', marker='o',
                    markersize=20, markerfacecoloralt='gray')
marker_style_green = dict(color='green', linestyle=':', marker='o',
                    markersize=20, markerfacecoloralt='gray')


def format_axes(ax):
    ax.margins(0.2)
    ax.set_axis_off()


def nice_repr(text):
    return repr(text).lstrip('u')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


y_ax = 1     
for y in data2:

    ax.text(-0.5, y_ax, nice_repr(y[6]) , **text_style)

    if y[0] == 0:
        ax.plot(y_ax * points[1], fillstyle='full', **marker_style_red)
    elif y[0] == 1:
        ax.plot(y_ax * points[1], fillstyle='full', **marker_style_green)
    y_ax += 1
    format_axes(ax)

plt.show()
```

But this does not work as bubbles is not changing according to values in array.
Adding a photo how should i want to look it like: [image]

And don't know how to have my array data as tabular form but with bubbles that colors according to data. Should i create lots of 1D lines and offset? If i use scatter , it might work for bubbles ,but how to show all other data next to bubbles? Or should i use `beautifulsoup` command and somehow add css to show tab as bubble?

Comment: Do you want lines as well or only the markers? Idea: Keep the original data and additionally split the data into two: one part with only `1` and `NaN` and one part with only `0` and `Nan`. Then you can plot the original data as line only, the first data-part with green markers and the second data-part with red markers. (If there is a `Nan` in the data, matplotlib just doesn't plot anything at this point) If you could give us a (non-working) minimal example we could help you further.

Comment: would be nice to have lines. problem is that i can see first column data regarding the value(green or red), but i can't get second and third column data next to it.  In given link points = np.ones(3) adds same clour to next bubble on horizontal axis , depending on the first column value. So in example TEST1 should be GREEN RED RED, but i get GREEN GREEN GREEN

Comment: Post the code, it's really hard to see why the method outlined above should fail, at least if I understand you correctly. The example you linked just plots the loop counter `y` times `1`, which means that the x-values are predefined as 0 to 4 (because that's the length of `ones(5)` and the y-values are 1 to 6. The color doesn't depend at all on any values. The loop just iterates over all possible fill styles and without multiplying with `y` all the dots would be at `y=1` (from `ones)`), overwriting each other.

Comment: Just do what @StefanS suggested, with another step: 1. plot only lines, 2. plot only greens, 3. plot only reds. Or if you don't want lines, you can use `scatter`.

Comment: StefanS, i posted code